# How can i navigate to different path on click in svelte?

Tags: onclick, navigation, svelte

Currently in having `on:click | preventDefault="{() => showDetail({id})}"`
and in `showDetail` function i want to naviagte to particular `id` which in i am passing on click of button.

I tried regular javascript method`location.assign` but this is reloading the page and destroying the purpose of SPA.
Is there any way to navigate in svelte without reloading

Comment: Look here for a solution with SvelteKit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187584/how-to-route-programmatically-in-sveltekit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a router. There are SPA routers (Single Page Application) and SSR router (Server Side Rendering).

You may try :

- https://routify.dev/
- https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing (server side)
- https://github.com/jorgegorka/svelte-router (SPA, seems not active project)
- https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router (SPA. I recommend it)
- http://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/
- https://github.com/lukeed/navaid
- https://github.com/TehShrike/abstract-state-router/

Comment: No, you don't. Path-based routing is built-in.

Comment: Routing does not come with https://svelte.dev/docs . Do you mean it is with SvelteKit ? https://kit.svelte.dev/docs