# How to change route on button click in Sapper?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I know it's possible to go to a route using

```
<a href="/example"></a>
```

but was wondering if it was possible with a button component alone and not by wrapping an `<a>` tag around the button.

what I am looking for is something similar to this:

```
<button goto={"/example"}>Goto a page</button>
```

Comment: Follow this answer asked on stack over flow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888502/how-can-i-navigate-to-different-path-on-click-in-svelte

Comment: Use [goto](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#goto_href_options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`goto`](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#goto_href_options) for this...

```html
<script>
  import { goto } from '@sapper/app';
</script>

<button on:click={() => goto('/example')}>Goto a page</button>
```

...but you probably shouldn't. Links are links, buttons are buttons. If something causes navigation, you're much better off using an `<a>` — using a button is bad for accessibility, bad for SEO, and bad for usability (no middle-click to open in new tab, etc). It's bad all around unless you *really* know what you're doing!

Comment: Thank for the `but`, I had to rethink my component and rewrote the component