# How to route programmatically in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I want to be able manage history of my SvelteKit app while simultaneously making sure the whole routing system of SvelteKit doesn't get affected in any way.

Something like:

```js
function routeToPage(route: string) {
   router.push(`/${route}`) // equivalent of this function
}
```

Answer (score 84):

Answering my own question thanks to Theo from SvelteKit Discord:

Use [$$app-navigation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation)

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

function routeToPage(route: string, replaceState: boolean) {
   goto(`/${route}`, { replaceState }) 
}
```

`replaceState == true` will replace the route instead of adding to the browser history. So, when you click back, you will not go back to the route you came from.

To go back use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

function goBack(defaultRoute = '/home') {
  const ref = document.referrer;
  goto(ref.length > 0 ? ref : defaultRoute)
}
```

Comment: where does `reflength` variable come from?

Comment: And also where/how would you use `goBack()`?

Comment: `reflength` is missing the dot operator: `ref.length`

Comment: This doesn't work, not explanatory enough

Comment: this doesn't work on server, i need to check if server mode and just ignore. seems nothing works on ssr really.

Comment: `state` can be used to modify the history:

`goto(\`/${route}\`, {state: \`/${route}\`});`

If you want to override the current history entry, use replaceState:true

Answer (score 36):

You can programmatically navigate to a route in Svelte-Kit using the [goto function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-navigation).
The most simple implementation would be something like this:

```
<script> 
  import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
  goto("/route")
</script>
```

But you can use more advanced options with it as well, which would be passed as a second argument with the target route.

Comment: `Cannot call goto(...) on the server`

Comment: This doesn't work properly. Problems occur with page refresh: 
Cannot call goto(...) on the server

Comment: On the server you should redirect in an endpoint

Comment: @Theoテオ what do you mean that? can you pls share an example

Comment: @seemcat An example would be to big for a comment, but here's the documentation for an endpoint https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints

Comment: Please post example. Also getting server error.

Comment: Hope it helps :3
https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/3245

Comment: You can do something like this: `import {browser} from "$app/environment"; 
if (browser) goto("/route");

You do have to import the goto function as well

Comment: Alternative to `browser`: `onMount(() => { goto('/route'); });`

Answer (score 7):

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

function routeToPage(route: string) {
  goto(route);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be not exactly what you're searching for, but I think it worth mentioning that can make use of the `beforeNavigate` callback provided by `$app/navigation`.

then, you can save the nav history in a store to use it across your application in order to manage some special cases.

***/routes/__layout.svelte***

```js
<script>
$: console.log($previousPage, $nextPage);

import { beforeNavigate } from "$app/navigation";
    beforeNavigate(({ from, to }) => {
    $history = [to.pathname, ...$history];
});
</script>

{#if $history}
  <ul>
    {#each $history as url}
      <li>{url}</li>
    {/each}
  </ul>
{/if history}
```

*side note: `from`& `to` are URL Objects from the Web API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL*

***/routes/stores.svelte***

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const history = writable(['/']);
```

Here's a demo based on the SvelteKit Demo app:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-wivfds?file=src%2Froutes%2Fstores.js&terminal=dev

Comment: The demo crashes with error: Error: Failed to load data
    at Renderer._load (https://sveltejskittemplatedefaultwivfds-gpaa--3000.local-corp.webcontainer.io/@fs/home/projects/sveltejs-kit-template-default-wivfds/.svelte-kit/runtime/client/start.js:1355:16)
    at async Renderer._get_navigation_result (https://sveltejskittemplatedefaultwivfds-gpaa--3000.local-corp.webcontainer.io/@fs/home/projects/sveltejs-kit-template-default-wivfds/.svelte-kit/runtime/client/start.js:1058:19)

Comment: It really rough and ready but it's the `todos` page that is returning an error, not crashing. I've just removed the api part so you can test it out once again