# Svelte - routing , When I try entering any url I only get "No webpage was found" error

Tags: html, typescript, routes, svelte

Using "svelte-routing" because I need to load a single page from lots of different urls , with the different urls serving as parameters.
For example if a client loads into my-sight/123 the sight needs to load the app.svelte component while passing 123 as a parameter.
The Problem is that whatever url I enter after the "my-sight/" I always get a "No webpage was found" page.
App.svelte:

```
<script script lang="ts">
  import MenuGenerator from './components/MenuSections/MenuGenerator.svelte';
  import { Router, Route } from 'svelte-routing';
</script>

<Router>
  <Route path="/:accomodation" component={MenuGenerator} />
</Router>
```

MenuGenerator.svelte:

```
<script script lang="ts">
  export let accomodation: string;
  console.log('hello ', accomodation);
</script>
```

I've tested this on https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-routing-forked-ztddj , just add anything after the / in the url and press enter and the same text is in the console.

Edit: We have QR codes and NFC tags, their urls are set and cannot be changed. The urls are my-sight/{qr_code} . I need routing that would redirect every possible url to home and pass in the {qr_code} as a value.

Comment: Its not totally clear on what you are doing, and why you are doing it that way. Are you trying to [do this?](https://svelte.dev/repl/340dac4861e8499ca4d4092214649c3c?version=3.37.0)  Your code as written says for any "/:id" always go to "Home"...

Comment: Are you trying to route via: `/my-sight?accomodation=123` ?  For that you would use a `get()` request, and `let accomodation_value = request.query.get("accomodation")`. Again, its not clear on where you are going here.

Comment: We have QR codes and NFC tags, their urls are set and cannot be changed. The urls are my-sight/{qr_code} . I need routing that would redirect every possible url to home and pass in the {qr_code} as a value.

Answer (score 0):

With that last edit / comment, your use case makes a whole lot more sense.

You can use [window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) in the browser to identify the QR Code within the URL.

```
<script>
  import { Router, Route } from "svelte-routing";
  import Home from "./routes/Home.svelte";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  onMount(()=>{
     let qr_code = window.location.pathname.substring(1);  // dump leading '/'
     console.log("qr_code: ", qr_code);
  })

</script>

  <Router>
    <div class="box">
      <Route path="/:id" component={Home} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

(edit)  This answer specifically address the need to" **I need routing that would redirect every possible url to home and pass in the {qr_code} as a value.**

It sounds now, like that is only a partial requirement.  (/edit)

Comment: Sadly still nothing, it's almost like no code gets ran at all when any other url is entered.
And sadly I cant really give you any error logs, if I enter any other url it just gives me a "No webpage was found" page. And yes I've added this code to my project:
`

  onMount(() => {
    let qr_code = window.location.pathname.substring(1); // dump leading '/'
    console.log('qr_code: ', qr_code);
  });
`

Comment: Yeah.. I will say, looking at this problem gave me a huge insight to SvelteKit. It seems a key function of [SvelteKit is to provide the router.](https://svelte.dev/faq#is-there-a-router)  Although you can use router to go to a dynamic route (`[id]-[category].svelte` you can only use `request.query` with and .js or .ts API style endpoint.

Comment: Ouch. What you are saying is with the current setup, you can manage NFC stuff, but absolutely nothing else (About Us, Contact Us, Normal menu item XXX, etc...)  Note: I suspect [this posting would be of help...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187584/how-to-route-programmatically-in-sveltekit)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED  !!!

I needed to uncomment a line of code in my snowpack config.

The line of code is:

```
//{ match: 'routes', src: '.*', dest: '/index.html' },
```

Tnx for the help !