# How to route programmatically in SveteKit 1.0?

Tags: routes, svelte, sveltekit

SvelteKit 1.0 has been out for a very short amount of time as per this writing, and I've encountered something that is nowhere in the new documentation. How can I route programmatically in SvelteKit 1.0? Before SvelteKit 1.0 there was a solution to do this, like it's written in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187584/how-to-route-programmatically-in-sveltekit). There was a goto function that did this (and now this function is out of the framework). You would've pass a route like "/homepage" and the function would route your app to the homepage page. How can I do this in SvelteKit 1.0? I have found nothing until now.

Comment: [`goto` still exists](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto). Are you trying to do a server side redirect?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that i have the default setting on my page, so I guess SSR is enabled. Yea, in this case, I am trying to do a server side redirect.

Comment: Nice. If you try to use `goto` in the top-level of your script tag it will be run on the server as well, which will not work as expected. You could put the logic in a `+page.server.js` file instead and use the built-in [`redirect` helper](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`goto` still exists](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#%24app-navigation-goto), but it is only usable in the browser (in an `onMount` callback, in an event handler, ...).

If you try to use it in the top-level of your page script tag it will be run on the server as well, which will not work as you might expect. You could e.g. create a `+page.server.js` file and use the built-in [`redirect` helper](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects) to do a server-side redirect instead.