# How to retrieve the sub-URL (e.g., '/page') of the previous page in Sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to find the sub-URL (e.g., '/page') of the previous page in my sveltekit website.

I tried the code below but its not working. Is there a way to get the previous page perhaps using sveltekit's in-built exports like `$page`?

```js
if (browser) {
        let previousUrl = document.referrer.substr(previousUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }
```

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: Have you tried https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-navigating?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187584/how-to-route-programmatically-in-sveltekit

Comment: @H.B. I want to show a modal when a user is coming from a certain route (plus some additional logic).

Comment: Can't you make it a query parameter before even navigating? Then you can just check that.